# Counting different values in a column in access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a column in Access table and it has different values, i just want to count number of records against each different value e.g

```
Column A   Count
4            3
4            3
4            3
3            2
3            2
1            1
```

Can anyone help me how to do this?

Comment: Have a look at total function Σ

Answer (score 0):

You do it using a query:

```
SELECT [Column A], Count([Column A]) AS CountOfColumnA
FROM tbl
GROUP BY [Column A];
```

Comment: Yes but it works if i have only 1 column to be counted
When i am doing this on multiple columns of a tables so its gives "1" in count column of every column.
I am using the sql as

SELECT Table1.Param1, Count(Table1.Param1) AS CountOfParam1, Table1.Param3, Count(Table1.Param3) AS CountOfParam3
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Param1, Table1.Param3;

Comment: Do them in separate queries

Comment: Thats the problem, i cant separately calculate for each column because i have approx 52 tables and each table has no. of columns